# CSS Grid - Moving items to the bottom of grid-square

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I am relatively new to HTML and am currently working on making a portfolio website.

https://jsfiddle.net/2b4sead0/

```
.grid-container {
  background-color: rgb(222, 224, 202);
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  display: inline-block;
}

.grid-item1 {
  padding: 1em;
  height: 33%;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.grid-item2 {
  padding: 1em;
  height: 33%;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.grid-item3 {
  padding: 1em;
  height: 33%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Here is what I have so far. I was wondering how I could make it so I can make certain text be at the bottom of a grid square.

Example: My grid is 1 column and 3 rows. Currently the text is at the top of each row. But I was wondering how I could reposition the text so that they are closer to eachother (in this case moving the "hi" to the bottom of the square so that it is right above "i'm andrew camilleri"). Meanwhile still making the grid span 100% so that it reformats when you view on any size screen.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't require any changes in your grid specific CSS.

I'd suggest you remove the margin on your `h2` element and set the `.grid-item1` class to

```
.grid-item1 {
  ...
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
}

.grid-item1__h2 { // Specific class for your h2 in case you want margins on other h2's
  margin: 0;
}
```

Something like this https://jsfiddle.net/kLchzod3/1/

Comment: Thank you! I was previously adding 'align-items: flex-end' without making sure display was set to flex. Quick question, is __ a common practice when specifying classes?

Comment: No, I'm just into the habit of using [BEM](http://getbem.com/) as a syntax for my CSS and class naming convention. It's useful and widely used, but it's a highly opinionated thing! :)